# Adding background resource in Java, with if/else or switch.

Tags: java, android, layout, background

I need help adding a background on android `slider.java`, so I want to have a background and to change it like this:

```
getBackground ( R.drawable_slider_bg);
if leftslider = PRESSED (getBackground = (R.drawable.slider_left_bg));
if rightslider = PRESSED (getBackground = (R.drawable.slider_right_bg));
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
// on slider.java

setBackgroundDrawable( R.drawable_slider_bg);

leftSlider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.slider_left_bg);
  }
};

rightSlider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.slider_right_bg);
  }
};
```

Comment: hy thanks for the help but unfortunaly it not working , somethink isnt heare right ? , what i need to edit from this code , cause on the slider.java i have STATE_PRESSED , and i see heare is the "onClick" somethink i need to import ?